# Php catch exception

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to catch an error

```
        try     
        {
            $outcome            =   $bet->getElementsByTagName("Outcome");
            $line1              =   $outcome->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("OptionalValue1")->item(0)->nodeValue;                      
            $line2              =   $outcome->item(2)->getElementsByTagName("OptionalValue1")->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $aOdds["line"]      =   ($line1 == 0) ? -$line2 : $line1;

            $aOdds["q1"]        =   $outcome->item(0)->getAttribute("odds"); 
            $aOdds["qx"]        =   $outcome->item(1)->getAttribute("odds"); 
            $aOdds["q2"]        =   $outcome->item(2)->getAttribute("odds");
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $outcome            =   $bet->getElementsByTagName("Outcome");
            $line1              =   $outcome->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("OptionalValue1")->item(0)->nodeValue;                      
            $line2              =   $outcome->item(1)->getElementsByTagName("OptionalValue1")->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $aOdds["line"]      =   ($line1 == 0) ? -$line2 : $line1;

            $aOdds["q1"]        =   $outcome->item(0)->getAttribute("odds"); 
            $aOdds["qx"]        =   0; 
            $aOdds["q2"]        =   $outcome->item(1)->getAttribute("odds");
        }
```

Some data comes with 2 same tag and the others with 3 and I want to catch if there not exist the 3. tag, but the error catching not really work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not really work?"

Comment: Something has to actually throw an exception for you to be able to catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read a little more about the concept of exceptions. Here are a few links that you might find useful:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

http://ciaweb.net/pear-exception-use-guidelines.html

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 1):

You can throw your own exception in the try block

```
if (some condition) {
  throw new Exception("Error message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that, in the try block code, an error will throw an exception?
The try statment is able to catch the exception which is threw by this php code:

```
throw new Exception('exception raised');
```

Please have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), in the Note pane.